# Load script only for returning USER - once!

Tags: javascript

I need a script which will load another script only for returning user!

The script which will need to load this script

```
<a href="http://www.w3.org/" >W3C</a>
```

I have a script which loads a popup only for new customers:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Script courtesy of http://www.web-source.net - Your Guide to Professional Web Site Design and Development
function GetCookie(name) {
var arg=name+"=";
var alen=arg.length;
var clen=document.cookie.length;
var i=0;
while (i<clen) {
var j=i+alen;
if (document.cookie.substring(i,j)==arg)
return "here";
i=document.cookie.indexOf(" ",i)+1;
if (i==0) break;
}
return null;
}
var visit=GetCookie("COOKIE1");
if (visit==null){
var expire=new Date();
window.name = "thiswin";
newwin=open("yourpagename.html", "dispwin", 
"width=450,height=455,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no");
expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+7776000000);
document.cookie="COOKIE1=here; expires="+expire;
}
// -->
</SCRIPT>
```

Yet I need the script only to load once for the returning customers every 1 day

thanks again

Comment: What is happening and would you want to happen?

Comment: Mwahahaha, “Your Guide to Professional Web Site Design and Development”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7776000000 equals 90 days.

Make the cookie expire every 24 hours [86400000] and you get once a day.

Comment: Ok thanks yet I need to know how to rewrite the above script so that 
    <a href="http://www.w3.org/" >W3C</a>  
Will be displayed only to returning customers ! (If it is allowed here to give money for the right answer then I will transfer 5 dollar to a given paypal account - if not then I redraw this offer)

Comment: Nothing?                                                                          hmmmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: replace the number for 90 days with the number for every 24 hours.